# Passing C instance to Python

Tags: python, c

Is it possible to send the C instance to a python code? Just to explain what I am trying to achieve:

I have a C code like this:

main.C

```
    #include <Python.h>

    int myCFunction(int someVariable)
    {
        // do some operation
    }

    int main()
    {
        Py_Initialize();
        PyObject *pName ...
        ...
        pName = PyString_FromString("example"); //Call example.py 
        ...
        pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "add"); // Call the method in example.py
        pArgs = PyTuple_New(3);
        pValue = PyInt_FromLong(3);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue);
        // I want to pass this instance as well, may be as a parameter
        // PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, /*instance?? */);
        return 0;
    }
```

---

My python program
example.py

```
    # Returns the sum of two numbers.
    def add(a, b, instance):
        # using the instance, I want to trigger C function 'myCFunction'
        return a+b
```

---

Can you let me know how I can achieve this? The reason for me to call back the C function is to update some data back and I do not want to do via return.

Comment: What means "the C instance" or "this instance"? Instance of what?

Comment: 'this' in programming mean the calling program instance. I want to call example.py from main.c and in the example.py call myCFunction (from the calling instance {this}) to update some value back.

Comment: So you're in fact asking two questions: 1) how do I call a Python function from C? 2) how do I call a C function from Python? Both of which are answered in the Python C API documentation.

Comment: No!! I am aware of the solution you are stating. Did you go through my above program? the call should be "C" -> "PY" -> "C". possible? PS: It's 1 question.

Comment: Thanks all, I figured out the solution. I create methods in C and then from C invoke Py code. Inside the Py code, I could now call the C functions. Code flow: (Method in C; From C -> (invoke) -> .py code; process .py code; From .py -> (invoke) -> The C method).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a wrapper around myCFunction that accepts and parses PyObject * and returns a PyObject *.  https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

Something like

```
PyObject* myCFunct(PyObject* args) {
    // do something
    return PyTrue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do you call this from example.py in my above example?